# JDBC ResultSet returns null from stored value in database

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I tried to get ResultSet from `Vertica` database with Java.
But it returns `null`.

SQL query:

```
SELECT to_char(SUM(my_column)) FROM my_table
UNION ALL SELECT to_char(123) FROM dual
```

SQL result in DB client:

```
201198184560.13000
123
```

[sql_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYGtV.png)

Java code:

```
PreparedStatement ps;
ps = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("Inside loop...");
    String str = rs.getString(1);
    Float f = rs.getFloat(1);
    Double d = rs.getDouble(1);
    Object obj = rs.getObject(1);
    System.out.println("String: " + str + ", float: " + f + ", double: " + d + ", obj: " + obj);
}
```

Result in java console:

```
Inside loop...
String: null, float: 0.0, double: 0.0, obj: null
Inside loop...
String: 123, float: 123.0, double: 123.0, obj: 123
```

What am I doing wrong?
Why Result Set returns null?
How can I print all my Result Sets in java console?

Update1:
Debug before while rs.next():

```
rs = {S4ForwardResultSet@1015} 
 m_logger = {DSILogger@1028} 
 m_resultMetaData = {S4ResultSetMetaData@1045} 
 m_currentRow = 0
 m_currentStream = null
 m_isOpen = true
 m_resultSet = {VResultSet@1046} 
 m_resultSetColumns = {ArrayList@1038}  size = 1
 m_warningListener = {SWarningListener@1047} 
 m_wasLastValueNull = false
 m_cachedDataWrappers = {ArrayList@1048}  size = 1
 m_cursorPosition = {CursorPosition@1049} "BEFORE_FIRST"
 m_columnNameIndexes = {ArrayList@1050}  size = 1
 m_numColumns = 1
 m_parentStatement = {VerticaJdbc4PreparedStatementImpl@996} 
 m_jdbcVersion = {JDBCVersion@1030} "JDBC4"
 m_streamBufferSize = 32000
```

Update2: 
Debug while rs.next() first time:

```
rs = {S4ForwardResultSet@1013} 
 m_logger = {DSILogger@1014} 
 m_resultMetaData = {S4ResultSetMetaData@1015} 
 m_currentRow = 1
 m_currentStream = null
 m_isOpen = true
 m_resultSet = {VResultSet@1016} 
 m_resultSetColumns = {ArrayList@1017}  size = 1
 m_warningListener = {SWarningListener@1018} 
 m_wasLastValueNull = true
 m_cachedDataWrappers = {ArrayList@1019}  size = 1
 m_cursorPosition = {CursorPosition@1078} "AT_FIRST"
 m_columnNameIndexes = {ArrayList@1021}  size = 1
 m_numColumns = 1
 m_parentStatement = {VerticaJdbc4PreparedStatementImpl@996} 
 m_jdbcVersion = {JDBCVersion@1022} "JDBC4"
 m_streamBufferSize = 32000
```

Debug while rs.next() second time:

```
m_logger = {DSILogger@1014} 
m_resultMetaData = {S4ResultSetMetaData@1015} 
m_currentRow = 2
m_currentStream = null
m_isOpen = true
m_resultSet = {VResultSet@1016} 
m_resultSetColumns = {ArrayList@1017}  size = 1
m_warningListener = {SWarningListener@1018} 
m_wasLastValueNull = false
m_cachedDataWrappers = {ArrayList@1019}  size = 1
m_cursorPosition = {CursorPosition@1087} "AT_LAST"
m_columnNameIndexes = {ArrayList@1021}  size = 1
m_numColumns = 1
m_parentStatement = {VerticaJdbc4PreparedStatementImpl@996} 
m_jdbcVersion = {JDBCVersion@1022} "JDBC4"
m_streamBufferSize = 32000
```

Update3: SQL looks like this:

```
with prov as
 (select ...
    from ...
    join ...
      on ...               
   where ...)
,
debet as
 (select prov....
    from prov
   where ...
   group by prov....
  ),
kredit as
 (select prov....
    from prov
   where ...
   group by prov....
  )

select 
    TO_CHAR(SUM(debet.sum_debet_rur)) SSS
from
    kredit full join debet 
    on ...
where (debet...) and (debet....)    

UNION ALL SELECT TO_CHAR(123) SSS from dual
```

Comment: Could you debug into your code and print out the full state of `rs` for the first row?

Comment: what database engine do you use?

Comment: Added Update1: Debug for the first row rs

Comment: That's not the first row. That would be before the first row. Can you post the debug result of `rs` afte the first call of `rs.next()`?

Comment: Added Update2 rs.next() first and second time

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand what Vertica's database engine is.

Comment: Where do you declare `sqlQuery`

Comment: I declared `sqlQuery` as `String sqlQuery = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("myFile.txt");`

Comment: That's not much use, is it? What is the actual SQL being executed? NB the content of the `ResultSet` before the first `next()` cannot possibly be of any interest.

Comment: My SQL looks like this:`with prov as
 (select ...
    from ...
    join ...
      on ...               
   where ...)
,
debet as
 (select prov....
    from prov
   where ...
   group by prov....
  ),
kredit as
 (select prov....
    from prov
   where ...
   group by prov....
  )

select 
 TO_CHAR(SUM(debet.sum_debet_rur)) SSS
from
 kredit full join debet 
 on ...
where (debet.year_dt=2015 or kredit.year_cr=2015) and (debet.month_dt =12 or kredit.month_cr =12)    

UNION ALL SELECT TO_CHAR(12345678901234567) SSS from dual`

Comment: Please try using rs.getString(0); instead of 1

Comment: It doesn't work: `Inside loop...
java.sql.SQLException: [Vertica][JDBC](10340) Invalid column index: 0.`

Comment: Are you using the same Vertica's jdbc driver than your DB Client? Same version? Happened to me many times that I used a different driver in my code than the one used at DB client and some features made me go cracy :-/. Try checking out [Release Notes](https://my.vertica.com/docs/ReleaseNotes/7.1.x/HP_Vertica_7.1.x_Release_Notes.htm). Notes of your driver/db versión of coure

Comment: @victorsosa Columns in JDBC are 1-based, so `getString(0)` is invalid.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks, I forgot that one

Comment: One more thing `to_char(SUM(my_column))`  in postgresql should be `select to_char(1234, '9999')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my SQL-query.

My JavaApp take SQL-query from file, that contains --comments.
After my JavaApp convert it to String and send to DB.

In Vertica you can check your queries using query:

```
select * from query_requests
order by start_timestamp desc
```

Thanks!